# Counting the number of common words in two different files

Tags: linux, file, shell, grep

I'm writing a shell script to count the number of common words between two different files, and I can't figure out how to do it. The only thing that is given is that I have to use `grep`.

For example, if my first file is:

```
egg
frog
horse
```

and the second one is:

```
dog
cat
egg
```

the output should be: `1`

Comment: this smells like homework, because I would use `awk` or `sort` or something else

Comment: If `grep` usage was optional, I would look at `sort`, `comm` and `wc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
words=`cat "file1"`
count=0
for word in $words; do
grep -q "$word" "file2" && ((count++))
done
echo "Number of match: $count"
```

Output:

```
Number of match: 1
```

`file1` is the path to file1 and `file2` is the path to file2

Answer (score 0):

try this

grep -f file1  file2  | wc -l